# Is there a brand new serialization as well as reflection library in C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, serialization, reflection, c++11

Recently, it's not impossible for boost serialization to refine with respect to stuff in C++11 standard library. Meanwhile I need a serialization as well as reflection library for my project. I searched around and didn't find any.

Therefore I'd like to know if there is existing one (hmm...it must be brand new to be C++11 compatible, not the aging MFC) or any basic, practical and explicit guidance about making my own. As far as I think, the rationale is to deduce on type with those helpers in STANDARD `<type_traits>`, which has already been adopted in boost serialization without std namespace.

This might be as insignificant to you as to pick pebble out of egg, but I just can't make myself happy with boost.

Comment: No, there isn't. Reflection will hopefully be part of C++14, but I don't know what is the status.

Comment: @Andy: I haven't seen a paper about reflection in the pre-Bristol mailing, which means there will be no reflection in C++14 - same goes for ranges.

Comment: @Xeo: That's sad news

Comment: "*Recently, it's not impossible for boost serialization to refine with respect to stuff in C++11 standard library.*" Um, what does that mean? How does Boost.Serialization "refine" with respect to anything?

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant there would probably be minor changes such as to use std::is_xxx instead of boost ones. Never mind anyway. I just can't stand using library for purpose of testbed in MY project. :-)

Comment: http://s11n.net/dream.php

Comment: What are you asking? Is there a serialization library in the C++11 standard? No. There isn't a reflection library either (type traits aren't really reflection)

Comment: @Pete I'm impressed. Alright, I won't complain anymore and just let it be. Question closed.

Answer (score 8):

To actually answer this, albeit a little late: There now is [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html) which is apparently exactly what you've asked for.

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want a complete serialization solution, maybe you can try [ROOT reflection](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/category/package-context/reflection). But this is not a light library. On the other hand, it's a complete solution.